# Angular-ui pagination in nested states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I have been strugling with this issue for some time.
I have a state (using ui-router) "videos", in this, I have pagination using angular-ui. Then I have a state "videos.lectionvideos" which is a child of the videos state. This child also contains pagination. But here comes the problem. The pagination work just fine, but it seems it works only in one direction. Pagination works on videos state, then I move to the child lectionVideos, there it works as well, but when I go back to the state videos, the previous state is kept, but it does not work anymore.
Here i a function which I am using for tha pagination:

```
$scope.SelectPage = function (page) {
        console.log('Navigate to page: ' + page);

        // next index of the first video
        var index = (page - 1) * $scope.videosPerPage;

        // start loading bar
        $scope.$emit('LOADING');

        // if we haven't already download it
        if($scope.recentVideos[index] === undefined)
        {
            // ... do some stuff
        }
        else
        {
            // ... do some stuff
        }
    }
```

When I try to navigate to other page, it does not go into to function at all, so I am guessing I have problem in the inheritance or in the passing the function or I dont know.
Here is JADE code for pagination:

```
 pagination(total-items='countVideos', page='currentPage', items-per-page='videosPerPage', max-size='10', on-select-page='pagiVideos.SelectPage(page)')
```

And here is the scope:

```
    // total number of videos to go through
    $scope.countVideos = data.countVideos || 0;

    // PAGINATION SETTINGS
    // current page
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    // index of the first item that appears on the page
    $scope.firstItemIndex = 0;

    // calculate correct number of videos on the page
    $scope.GetNumbers = function () {
        var p = $scope.firstItemIndex + $scope.videosPerPage;
        p = (p > $scope.countVideos ? (p - $scope.countVideos) : $scope.videosPerPage);
        return $scope.GetNums(p);
    };
```

And part of the state code:

```
   $stateProvider
        .state('videos', {
            url : '/videos',
            templateUrl : '/partials/videos.html',
            controller : 'VideosCtrl',
            resolve : {
                  // resolve stuff
            },
            title : 'Videos',
            menuItem : 'Videos'
        })
        .state('videos.videosLection', {
            url : '/:lection',
            templateUrl : '/partials/videosLection.html',
            controller : 'VideosLectionCtrl',
            menuItem : 'Videos',
            resolve : {
                // resolve stuff
            }
        })
```

Anyone any ideas? I have tried wrapping the variables into object, no luck there.

### Edit

I have found the same problem but in simpler version. I think this is the issue I am dealing with. Here is the code:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: '/partials/about.html'
        })
        .state('about.stateone', {
            url: '/one',
            template: '<p>State one</p><p><test-d v="1"></test-d></p>'
        })
    ;
```

This is state settings, here are the directive for test-d:

```
.directive('testD', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            fn : '&',
            v : '@'
        },
        controller : ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.fun = function () {
                console.log('greetings from directive: ' + $scope.v);
            }
        }],
        template: '<div><p>Var: {{v}}</p>' +
            '<button ng-click="fun()">SEND</button></div>'
    }
})
```

And the HTML (JADE) for the about state looks like this:

```
ui-view
        p Default content
        test-d(v='0')
```

So it seems, that the default content gets somehow overwritten, when I am going back to it. The problem is, when I hit the button in about state, works, then go to state one where it works as well, but going back to about, the button does not work anymore. What am I not seeing?

Comment: Solution
======== Here is this issue discussed with developers: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/734

Comment: Hey man, if you think that's the best solution to your question, may I suggest you write up an answer here and answer your own question? 
I know other people probably have this question, and we can all up-vote you for helping us. Thanks!